# What is A intersection B'

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was answering the questions in my book and came over the question: What is A intersection B complement? I thought the answer would be shading everything EXCEPT the middle part where  A and B intersect, but instead when I check my answer from the back, the ONLY thing they shaded was the middle part where A and B intersect. Could anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please read the guidelines in the Help Centre!

Comment: It should be only the part inside A but also outside B.

Comment: It's worth noting that if your book shaded $A\cap B,$ then your book's answer is wrong. The answer you were thinking of would be correct for $(A\cap B)',$ but this is not the same as $A\cap B'.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\cap B^C$ is the definition of $A\setminus B$: everything that is in $A$, but not in $B$. A corresponding Venn-diagram is here:
${}\rlap{\raise3cm{\hskip1.5cm\color{white}{A\setminus B}}}$
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!